# The most performant way to merge N lists, track duplicates, and sort them by date

Tags: list, sorting, haskell, merge, grouping

I am new to Haskell and am wanting to know the most efficient way to merge an arbitrary number of lists of an arbitrary number of items. Here's example data:

```
LIST 1: steve
2014-01-20 | cookies  | steve

LIST 2: chris
2014-02-05 | cookies  | chris

LIST 3: mark
2014-09-30 | brownies | mark
2014-03-30 | candy    | mark
2014-05-12 | pie      | mark

LIST 4: anthony
2014-05-18 | cookies  | anthony
2013-12-25 | fudge    | anthony

LIST 5: andy
2014-10-04 | cookies  | andy

LIST 7: john
2014-06-19 | pie      | john


RESULTING LIST
2014-10-04 | cookies  | andy chris steve anthony
2014-09-30 | brownies | mark
2014-06-19 | pie      | john mark
2014-03-30 | candy    | mark
2013-12-25 | fudge    | anthony
```

Notice the lists are all oriented around people and may or may not be sorted by date, and the result needs to merge the prior lists, group and create a list where the dessert is unique but has a list of the constituent people who ate it, sorted by date reverse chronologically.

Comment: Sounds like you really want a database.  Also, I would be wary of trying for the "most performant" algorithm before benchmarking.  As many have said before me, early optimization is bad.  Get it working, then run a profiler to figure out where your bottlenecks are, optimize those spots, and repeat until your happy with the performance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have coded this in Java and C++ and have gotten reasonable results. I've tried doing it in Postgres and it's been very slow no matter what I have tried. (Creative indexing and such)

Answer (score 1):

What is the most performant way to solve a problem, is in most cases not answerable neither in haskell nor in any other programming language I think.

A better approach would be to think about, how can I solve this problem (at all) and keep a few principles in the back of your mind.

- testability
- abstraction and expressiveness
- maintainability
- readability
- performance

Maybe I've forgot about something but for your problem I want to give a hintlist

If I know all the items and names in advance I would use algebraic datatypes to model this situation

```
data Name  = Mark | Chris ...
           deriving (Ord,Eq,Show)
data Items = Pie | Cookies ...
           deriving (Ord,Eq,Show)
```

If I do not already know how haskell represents a date datatype I can use a plain old `String` to model this, or I would use hoogle to see if there already exists a date-thingy.

```
> hoogle date
...
Data.Time.Calendar...
...
```

So I guess the `Data.Time.Calendar` module seems a good choice for that, and I would look at its documentation which can both be found [online](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time) or if you install the package locally you can use haddock to generate it yourself from the source files.

Next step I would approach is to model the "database" of course there exists libraries to work with sqly stuff or acid-state a database that uses algebraic datatypes instead of a database backend. But for getting a better grasp of haskell I would try to reinvent the wheel for once and use either a list of tupels, or a dictionary-like collection, which is in haskell called `Map`. But working with `Map` one has to be careful and do a qualified import as most of its provided functions would lead to a name collision with the functions in the standard library (Prelude).

```
import qualified Map as M
```

and to model my database I would use the Items as keys and a tuple of date and list of names as the values and as I want to be aware that this is my database I would provide a type alias for that.

```
type DB = M.Map Item (Date, [Name])
```

For working with that I would again have a glance at the `Map` docu and be happy to find the functions `insertWith`, `empty` and `toList`. And for the `insertWith` functions I would think of a mixture of `max` and list cons `(:)` functions to make new entries.
To get a better feel for the whole thing I would fire up `ghci` and `import qualified Data.Map as M` and fool around with some examples using `M.Map String (String,[Int])` or whatnot to model my data in a first approximation.

For the result I have to sort the `toList` of my Map by date, which is just a little problem. The type of my `toList myDb` is `[(Item,(Date,[Name]))]` so sorting by the `fst.snd` with `sortBy` should lead to the desired result.

After I'd done this much, I'd take a break and read something about parsers - to get all my files in context with my program. A search with the search engine of your least distrust will turn up a few articles worth reading (Parser Parsec Haskell).
If all of this is too complicated I would go back and change all my types to be `Strings` and hope I wouldn't have any typeos until I had time to read again about parsers ;-).

For any problems in the intermediate steps people here will be glad to help you, assumed you provide a *concrete* question/problem description.

If all of this were not performant enough, the profiling tools provided by haskell are good enough to help me, but this is my last concern to solve.